# Microsoft Graph: get users of a SharePoint group

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to query over SharePoint groups, for example:

- Get users of a group
- Know if a user is inside a group

Or query over a user and get his SP groups ?

Comment: To clarify what you're looking for when you say SP Groups: do you mean 'Owner', 'Visitor', etc? Or do you mean custom Office 365 groups?

Comment: I'm new in SP, i think it's SP groups, with SharePoint Rest Api the uri would be like: .../_api/web/sitegroups('85')/users